# Help identifying fruit

Tags: species-identification

This fruit was spotted in Kochi, India on several occassions. Nothing else is known except the fact that it seems to be irregularly distributed through Kerala.
[image: fruit]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be a noni fruit ([Morinda Citrifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morinda_citrifolia)).

[image]